# How to add java plugin to firefox profile using selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, java-6

I want to add java 6 plugin to firefox profile using java code and selenium.

Please any one help how to add plugin to profile

Answer (score 1):

```
File file = new File("java 6 plugin file");
FirefoxProfile firefoxProfile = new FirefoxProfile();
firefoxProfile.addExtension(file);
firefoxProfile.setPreference("extensions.firebug.currentVersion", "1.8.1"); 
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(firefoxProfile);
```